# Setting focus on dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code which generates bunch of tabs

```
<li ng-repeat="nav in navs">
    <a href="" id="{{$index}}" ng-class="{'selected-nav': nav.state === selectedTab}" tabindex="{{nav.state === selectedTab ? 0 : -1}}">
       <span>Some icon</span>
       <span>Some text</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Now, i want to navigate through these tabs using arrow keys, I mean i want the focus to move to next element if I use right arrow key and want to move focus to previous element using left arrow key.

I tried this, but it's not gonna work because the elements are generated dynamically, any help??

```
if(event.which === 39 || event.which === 40) {
document.getElementById('1').focus();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try adding `tabindex=0` to the `<a>` to make this element focus-able.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html explains that among other (less relevant) restrictions, tag IDs need to start with a letter.

Comment: And where do you have that code that listens to an event?

Comment: @DanFarrell They can begin with a number... CSS is not found of it, but it works in modern browsers. That is HTML 4 spec, not same in HTML5.

Comment: @epascarello element.bind("keydown", function (event)

Comment: Well since you are using angular to set the classes, why are you not just updating the object with which one is selected?

Comment: @epascarello can give me an example please